# Does Hibernate 5 still support Hibernate Spatial?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x, hibernate-spatial

According to the following link:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/quickstart/html_single/#_release_bundle_downloads

There should be a folder "lib/spatial" that contains the hibernate spatial jars, however it seems to be the one folder missing in the lib folder from the standard download. (I've tried Hibernate versions 5.0.6, 5.0.8 & 5.1.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate 5 is not supported *yet*. If you check the official website:

[hibernatespatial](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/)

You will see:

> Compatibility with Hibernate ORM
>
> ```
> Hibernate Spatial version 4.3 is compatible with Hibernate 4.3.x only
> Hibernate Spatial version 4.0 is compatible with Hibernate 4.x only
> Hibernate Spatial version 1.1.x is compatible with Hibernate 3.6.x
> Hibernate Spatial version 1.0 is compatible with Hibernate 3.2.x - 3.5.x
> ```

But do not be afraid, the work has already started on Version 5. There is already a hibernate spatial jar uploaded [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-spatial/5.1.0.Final), but it is less than a month old.

Comment: Thanks, since Hibernate 5 is already released, I presumed it was already included as part of the Hibernate 5 core as you would expect from what they said on the Hibernate Spatial site: "We are currently working on migrating Hibernate Spatial to a module of the Hibernate ORM project. The move will be complete by the time of the Hibernate 5 release."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the move has been completed, and hibernate-spatial is now part of Hibernate 5.x.

You can always get access to the jars using http://search.maven.org/ (just search for hibernate-spatial).

I'll ask on the hibernate mailing list why it isn't included in the lib folder as documented.